# Hash() of custom object not 'random'

Tags: python, hash

## In short:

I noticed that applying the `hash()` function on a custom object always returns a value that is a multiple of 4, plus 1. Is there a reason for this, and a way to stop this from happening?

I suppose, if this is *always* the case, I could subtract 1 and divide by 4 to get a "dense" distribution of `hash` values, but I'm unsure if this indeed so.

## Verbose / with example:

In `Python`, I have a bunch of custom objects, and a (short) list of values. For each object, I want to pick a value in the list, so, that

- All values are equally likely to be picked; and
- I get the same value for each object should I repeat the process at a later point in time.

It is not problematic that some objects will be paired to the same value.

My idea was to use the objects' `hash()` value for this (they do not have a user-defined `__hash__` method implemented), in such a way:

```
value = list_of_values[hash(object) % len(list_of_values)]
```

However, I noticed, some values from the list were never picked, and upon inspection, the `hash` values are always a multiple of 4, plus 1 - which is a problem if the length of the `list_of_values` is a multiple of 4.

I'd be helped with either

- a way to make the `hash` function return a value that is not the multiple of any value; or
- the confirmation that it is *always* a multiple of 4, irrespective of class, operating system (32 or 64 bits, Windows or Linux or Mac), etc.; or
- a different way to consistenty produce the same semi-random number from an object.

Comment: Because then I couldn't repeat the process and get the same value

Comment: Have you implemented the `__hash__` function for your objects? Can we see that definition?

Comment: @ElRudi Sure you can. That's what `random.seed` is for: call that with a known value, and the sequence of random values is fixed.

Comment: @mypetlion, thanks for your comment. The class is not written by me, and it does not have a custom `__hash__` function implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's funny how writing up a question focuses the mind. While typing my question, the answer came to me: I *first* take the modulo of the `hash` value with a prime number, and *then* the modulo with the length of the list:

```
value = list_of_values[(hash(object) % prime) % len(list_of_values)]
```

The prime number should be less than the typical `hash`-value, but more than several times the length of the `list_of_values`. As the `list_of_values` has less than a few 100 elements in my case, I took the value 7919.

(To see why the latter is important: suppose the `list_of_values` has a length of 100, and the value of `prime` is `113`. In that case, the first modulo (`hash(object) % prime`) gives a value from 0 to 112, which are all equally likely. If I then take the modulo with `100`, the numbers `0..99` stay the same, and those `100..112` are reduced to `0..12`. This makes that the first 13 elements have double the probability of being picked, compared to the other elements.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want repeatable random sequences, call `random.seed` using a known value.

```
>>> random.seed(3)
>>> [random.choice("abc") for x in range(10)]
['a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a']
>>> random.seed(3)
>>> [random.choice("abc") for x in range(10)]
['a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a']
```

The fact that both lists are identical is not a coincidence.

---

Based on your comment, I think you can use a `defaultdict`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> import random
>>> values = [1,2,3,4]
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: random.choice(values))
>>> [d['foo'] for _ in range(20)]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

The first lookup for any given key is chosen at random, then remembered. Subsequent lookups always use that first value.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that trick. Many thanks! I'm still wondering about the implementation though. See, if I understand the `.seed` correctly, it determines/resets the values that are being chosen: after calling `random.seed(3)`, the first call of `random.choice('abc')` returns 'a', the second 'b', etc. Right? However, to use this in my example, I have to also keep my *objects* in some order. I can't take a random object and easily find its corresponding value. I'd have to find it's number in the order, reset the seed, and call `.choice` that many times, is that correct?

Comment: Hm. Maybe what you want instead is a default dict, which you can use to defer the choice of a random value for you object until the first time you do the look up. `d = defaultdict(lambda: random.choice(some_list))`. The first time you access `d[foo]`, you'll pick a value at random, but that choice will be remembered and used for `foo` each subsequent lookup.

Comment: I didn't mention it in the question, but I can in fact not store any data for later use that way. All I have are the objects and the list of values. Otherwise, the dictionary route would definitely be a good one to go. I suppose I could also just add the value to the object `if not hasattr(object, 'my_special_value'): object.my_special_value = ...`, and retrieve it from there later... but that feels like I'm abusing someone else's class :) So I always try to avoid solving it that way.